# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[p]{1+a_{n}}-1}{a_{n}}$ if lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $a_{n}=$0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question** Assume that a positive sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$. For natural $p\geq 2$, determine 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[p]{1+a_n}-1}{a_n}
> $$

**MY Approach**

Let $x_{n}=\sqrt[p]{a_{n}+1}$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n} = 1\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[p]{a_{n}+1}-1}{a_{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n}-1}{x_{n}^{p}-1}$$

If i take $p=2\implies \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[2]{1+a_{n}}-1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$

If i take $p=3 \implies\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+a_{n}}-1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Is it coincidence ? If not then how to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[p]{1+a_{n}}-1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{p}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use that $(a^p-1)=(a-1)(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+\cdots+1)$, with $a=x_n$. Hence,
$$
\frac{x_n-1}{x_n^p-1}=\frac{1}{x_n^{p-1}+\cdots+x_n+1}.
$$

Comment: Got it Thanks brother

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/p}$. Then $\frac{\sqrt[p]{1+a_{n}}-1}{a_{n}}= \frac{f(a_n)-f(0)}{a_n-0} \to f'(0)$.

Comment: Sir, you made the question look too easy